# Go SQL segmentation violation on query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go

I'm trying to do some queries on my postgresql database.

My main func is something like that :

```golang
psqlInfos := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)

db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfos)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error while opening the database : ", err)
    return
}
defer db.Close()

err = db.Ping()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error while connecting to database : ", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println("Successfully connected !")
```

Everything seems to be ok since it displays "Successfully connected !"

However when I try to do a simple query like

```golang
query := `
    SELECT *
    FROM table
        `
rows, err := db.Query(query)
```

I have this error

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x4cce73]
```

I don't know where this problem is coming from

Comment: How is `db` passed to the querying function?

Comment: it's a global var

Comment: In main, you are initializing it with `db, err:=...`. That redeclares it as a local var. Use `db, err=...`

Comment: @BurakSerdar is work when I do the query in the main func, do you know why ?

Comment: @BurakSerdar ok thank you I'm just stupid

Comment: is look like you have deferred  DB.close so when you call it has been already closed

Answer (score 0):

The error shows a problem with accessing memory, and you don't have that access.

---

One possible reason is the SQL query. It is not executed correctly.

Debug this and print the error by `db.Query()` fun to see the information.

##### This worked for me:

```
rows, err := db.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error executing query: ", err)
    return
}
defer rows.Close()
```

It will print out the error message in the query.

Make sure the `table` exists in `database`.

---

Other possible issue is how you're handling the `db.Query()` rows.

You call `db.Query()` -> `*sql.Rows` obj that can be `iterated` over the results.

You have to properly handle the rows because you can end up with memory errors.

Avoid this calling `Close()` on the rows obj when you're done using it. This will release any res associated with the rows.

##### This always work for me:

```
query := `SELECT * FROM table`

rows, err := db.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error executing query:", err)
    return
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    // Process each row here...
}

if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error iterating over rows:", err)
    return
}
```

`defer rows.Close()` call `Close()` when the fun is returned, also the loop ensures that all the rows are processedd, and any error that occur in the iteration is reported.